# Grammatical role of "kind of"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

I would like to know what the grammatical construct "kind of + v" is?

> I *kind of* like cold weather

or

> I *kind of* eat everything".

Comment: [Kind of](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kind) in ODO: *informal* rather; to some extent.

Comment: Although it's informal, I suppose it's classed as an adverb.

Comment: To whoever marked it as GR, try to find this information easily...

Comment: @mplungjan http://www.onelook.com/?w=kind+of&ls=a

Comment: Right. I now see the adverb. Most of them say "Idiom"

Comment: Knowing it's an idiom is more valuable than knowing it's an adverb; knowing it's an adverb tells you nothing you don't already know, but idioms have to be specified as such.

Answer (score 3):

*Kind of* and the synonym *sort of* are classified as non-standard synonyms of the **adverb** *somewhat*

http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000231.htm

> The expressions kind of or sort of to mean "rather," "partially," or "somewhat" are nonstandard.
>
> Both expressions literally mean "type of" or "variety of."

So I would also classify them as adverbs